Disable npm commands in specific directory
I am working on a project that is being managed using the bun package manager. But I am habitual to use npm commands in directories, for installing deps or running the local server.
I am skeptical that using npm inside a directory managed by bun would have some unintended side effects, like unexpected changes to package.lock.json that might break  installation for other developers who use bun.
So, I want a way on my linux (Ubuntu) machine to block myself from using npm commands in this particular directory / repository. Like, if I try to run an npm command, I shall get an error saying npm commands are disabled in this directory. Use bun instead., if possible.
I don't prefer to change PATH specificity to override npm because each time I shift to an npm project, I would need to change that again. Changing path alias is not a solution I prefer as well because I would need to remember to change it each time I start or finish working. Any other suggestions are welcome.

This sounds like XY problem. I see no problems with running npm commands in general. If you care about side effects then address them specifically. E.g. add devEngines and engines to package.json. Add env check because it's that you use node and not bun that primarily matters for a script. Add preinstall script to check pm. Add precommit hook to check if there's package lock, because bun has a different lock file
